# Django contact form not working. GMAIL not recieving message

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-email

I am trying to use a simple contact form using Gmail configuration. 
When users click sends message button it reloads to should reload to the home page and should send messages to hosted email.

I don't get any email with this process. I don't understand where I am going wrong.

**Forms.html**

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

                <form  action="{% url 'home' %}" method="post" id="contactForm" name="sentMessage" novalidate="novalidate">
                    <!--  -->
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="row align-items-stretch mb-5">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" name="message_name" placeholder="Your Name *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name." />
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" name="message_email" placeholder="Your Email *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address." />
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-md-0">
                                <input class="form-control" id="phone" type="tel" name="message_phone" placeholder="Your Phone *" required="required"/>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-textarea mb-md-0">
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message_text" placeholder="Your Message *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center form-group">
                        <div id="success"></div>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" id="sendMessageButton" type="submit">Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

**view.py File**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'resumesite/forms.html', {})

def form(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
      message_name = request.POST('message_name')
      message_email = request.POST('message_email')
      message_phone = request.POST('message_phone')
      message_text = request.POST('message_text')

      send_mail(
           'message_name', #subject
           'message_text', #message
           'message_email', #from_email
           ['chaitu.orakala@gmail.com'],#to_email

        )
      return render(request, 'resumesite/forms.html', {'message_name': message_name})
     else:
        return render(request, 'resumesite/forms.html', {})
```

**settings.py file**

```
import os
import django_heroku
from decouple import config
import dj_database_url
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'm*8e65ela2^)hdb-yl&j!%_!e8p*)+_%1(l&a#jw6rwlds17o*'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin'
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'resumesite',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djangoresume.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djangoresume.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
      os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

django_heroku.settings(locals())

# Email config
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'privacy reasons too7k it off'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'privacy reasons took off'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Project Tree

[image]

Comment: Your form's action is this `action="{% url 'home' %}"` but you have a view named `home` that does nothing with the submitted form. Are you sure that the URL named `home` uses your view named `form`? Maybe show your `urls.py`.

Comment: Yes, You are right. I made a mistake in urls.py and corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending dummy email with django shell if not successful edit the email config as below

Try modifying # Email config

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'privacy reasons too7k it off'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'privacy reasons took off'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'youremail@gmail.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'youremail@gmail.com'
```

Comment: I tried changing to below code, I didn't see any difference, sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
def form(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
      message_name = request.POST('message_name')
      message_email = request.POST('message_email')
      message_phone = request.POST('message_phone')
      message_text = request.POST('message_text')
```

Changed to code to following then it worked.

```
def form(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
      message_name = request.POST['message_name']
      message_email = request.POST['message_email']
      message_phone = request.POST['message_phone']
      message_text = request.POST['message_text']
```